# How to copy active range from one sheet and pasting the data to a specific range in a different sheet within the same workbook in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to copy the selected range from one sheet and paste it into a specific range in a different sheet within the same workbook. How would this be done? thanks in advance.

Below is my current attempt which i cant quite get to work.

```
function Copy() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J-gKl2AmLZOGxrcV7otTudhcHggLwThojmri6j3KFI0"); 

 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Mold Repair Request'); 

 var range = ss.getActiveRange(); 

 var data = range.getValues();


 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J-gKl2AmLZOGxrcV7otTudhcHggLwThojmri6j3KFI0"); 

 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('TAG-005DB Red'); 

 ts.getRange('F2').setValues(data); 

}
```

Comment: what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: `.setValues` expects a 2D array. Change your last line to `ts.getRange('F2').setValues([data])`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to reopen the spreadsheet. Remove `var tss = ...` and change `var ts = sss.getSheetByName(...)` because you're already _in_ the spreadsheet you want to work in.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Copy() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J-gKl2AmLZOGxrcV7otTudhcHggLwThojmri6j3KFI0"); 

  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Mold Repair Request'); 
  var range = ss.getActiveRange(),
      numRows = range.getNumRows(),
      numColumns = range.getNumColumns();

  var data = range.getValues();

  // ---

  var ts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TAG-005DB Red');

  range = ts.getRange('F2');
  var col = range.getColumn(),
      row = range.getRow(); 

  ts.getRange(row, col, numRows, numColumns)
    .setValues(data);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```